# ProtocolViolationException when doing a WebRequest with GET

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, http-get

I'm trying to gather data from a public API for a Windows Phone app.

```
private void GatherPosts()
{
    string url = baseURL + "?after=" + lastPostId + "&gifs=1";
    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
    request.ContentType = "text/json";
    request.Method = "GET";

    AsyncCallback callback = new AsyncCallback(PostRequestFinished);
    request.BeginGetResponse(callback, request);
}

private void PostRequestFinished(IAsyncResult result)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(result);
}
```

But I keep getting a `ProtocolViolationException` on the last line of the callback method with the message `A request with this method cannot have a request body.`. I read that it's because I'm trying to send data, which is obviously forbidden for the GET protocol, but I don't see where I'm doing it, i.e. how to avoid it.

Comment: Try commenting the line where you set the `ContentType`. Afaik, json requests will always have a BODY, which is not the case for a `get`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's probably the `ContentType` that makes it think there is a request body, thus the exception.

You would want to set `Accept-Encoding` instead.

Comment: Worked gracefully. I don't think I need the Accept-Encoding, since the specification says it will always be JSON.